# How to save objects to txt file in java

Tags: java

This is my code

```
package week14_class_work;

public class StudentMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Student[] s = new Student[3];
        s[0] = new Student("Kim", "PROGRAM", 101, "010-1234-5678");
        s[1] = new Student("lee", null, 102, "010-9876-7766");
        s[2] = new Student("jung", "ABCDEF", 103, "010-6767-3322");

        System.out.println("****************************************");
        for (Student t_s : s)
        {
            t_s.printData();
            System.out.println("****************************************");
        }

        System.out.println("총인원 수: " + Member.member_count);
        StudentFile sf = new StudentFile("test.txt", s);
    }
}
```

```
package week14_class_work;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.io.*;

public class Student extends Member implements Serializable
{
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String tel;
    private int num;

    Student(String id, String pwd, int num, String tel)
    {
        super(id);
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.num = num;
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public void printData()
    {
        if (is_ok_pwd(pwd) == false)
        {
            pwd = gen_pwd();
        }
        String date;
        GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("2020년 6월 18일 ahh:mm:ss");
        date = sdf.format(today.getTime());
        System.out.println(id + " " + pwd + " " + num + " " + tel + " " + date);
    }
}
```

```
package week14_class_work;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class SHA256Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String msg = "I am s student.I am a student";
        byte[] sha256_result = sha256(msg);
        System.out.println(bytesToHex1(sha256_result));
    }

    public static byte[] sha256(String msg) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(msg.getBytes());
        return md.digest();
    }

    public static String bytesToHex1(byte[] bytes)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes)
        {
            builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Now my question is When I set the second value of S[1] to `null`, the program throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` exception...
Also, the teacher asked us to use the `StudentFile`class to save the Student calss object and use the `SHA256` function to encrypt the `pwd` in the `Student` class and save it to a txt file. I want to know how to di it?
Tannks! I have no idea to do my homework in this week....

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the null pointer exception, it seems like you just aren't handling the null case.

Your code:

```java
Student[] s = new Student[3];
s[0] = new Student("Kim", "PROGRAM", 101, "010-1234-5678");
s[1] = new Student("lee", null, 102, "010-9876-7766");
s[2] = new Student("jung", "ABCDEF", 103, "010-6767-3322");

// You set s[1] to null, right?
s[1] = null;

System.out.println("****************************************");
for (Student t_s : s) // here, you unpack the array into individual items
{
    // On s[1], t_s will be null
    t_s.printData(); // which means t_s.printData() is actually null.printData()... which will produce a null pointer exception
    System.out.println("****************************************");
}
```

Fixing the null pointer is pretty straight forward:

```java
for (Student t_s : s) 
{
  if (t_s != null) 
  {
    t_s.printData();
    System.out.println("****");
  }
}
```

---

Saving an object to a file:
You're going to need to encode the file into some string format. It looks like you get this out of the box with Serializable. Per the documentation, if you need to do something special, you're going to need to overload this methods:

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
```

In your case, you need to do two things:

1. Overload writeObject, and write out each field in your Student class. I think via something like `out.defaultWriteObject(this.num)` except for password, which you'll need to hash first, per your homework, then again use `out.defaultWriteObject(passwordHash)`
2. You need to do the opposite on readObject -- consult the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

As an alternative, you could also: encode to json, xml, or some other standard format. Likewise, java also supports DataInputStream and DataOutputStream, which put more control in your hands. Note that only you and your instructor can decide what's appropriate for this assignment -- Serailizable seems like a reasonable approach, so I'd try to make that work before diving into other solutions.

Good Luck!

Comment: I thought he wanted it as a text file.. so I didn't suggest using serialization.. 
I think just manually writing text would be much simpler than dealing with serialization

Comment: The example code was already serialized, so I stuck with that. Given that it's homework, my thought was that serialization, specifically, was the goal. Agreed though: if all you need to do is write a file and you don't care about how it's written, you can just use something like print writer to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to write text to a file is using PrintWriter:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
   pw.println(myString);
}
```

You'll need to decide what to do with the IOExceptions it may throw.

Comment: Yes .but i should make ```StudentFile``` class to save ```Student```class to a txt file. I want know how to make this ```StudentFile```class

Comment: Maybe make a class that "represents" the file.. ie.. it takes care of making changes and writing to the PrintWriter?
Maybe they mean its a container of students that can be "saved". Where saving means to write all the students to the file?

Comment: Yes. All three student objects in the code need to be written to the file, and the pwd in them also needs ot be encrypted.This is the function of the StudentFile class i need to write

Comment: so create a class where you can add students and related info.. and implement a save() method.